# Run every file in a folder

Tags: r

Can I write one R script to open and run every R file in a folder?

I know how to check for the presence of a file in a folder, how to read every file in a folder as a text connection and how to read every data file in a folder.

However, I want to execute every R script in a folder one at a time, ideally using a single R script and the default R gui installed on a Windows desktop during installation.

I suspect I might need to run R from the command line instead and write some sort of batch file to do this.  I have rarely run R from the command line and never written a batch file for R.

Here are some example R scripts all stored in a folder named `run_all_these`:

The file `run.one.r` contains:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a+b
c
```

The file `run.two.r` contains:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a-b
c
```

The file `run.three.r` contains:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a*b
c
```

The file `run.four.r` contains:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a/b
c
```

I found virtually nothing on this topic using Google.  Although, I did find a little on batch files here:

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html

My actually R scripts will each create their own output files when run.  So, I am mostly concerned with running the R scripts right now.  Although the next step would be to open each R script, change `a` from `10` to `100` and run them again.  Perhaps that should be a follow-up post.

Thank you for any suggestions.

**EDIT** Nov 20, 2013:

After discussion with Ricardo Saporta below I changed the four input files to:

File `run.one.r`:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a+b
print(c)
```

File `run.two.r`:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a-b
print(c)
```

File `run.three.r`:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a*b
print(c)
```

File `run.four.r`:

```
a <- 10
b <- 20
c <- a/b
print(c)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have used `source` to read a single R file, but never thought to use it to execute every file in a folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the following function in my utils file:

```
## finds all .R files within a folder and soruces them
sourceEntireFolder <- function(folderName, verbose=FALSE, showWarnings=TRUE) { 
  files <- list.files(folderName, full.names=TRUE)

  # Grab only R files
  files <- files[ grepl("\\.[rR]$", files) ]

  if (!length(files) && showWarnings)
    warning("No R files in ", folderName)

  for (f in files) {
    if (verbose)
      cat("sourcing: ", f, "\n")
    ## TODO:  add caught whether error or not and return that
    try(source(f, local=FALSE, echo=FALSE), silent=!verbose)
  }
  return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

Comment: Better design than my quick and dirty approach. One could also imagine that data files might be in the same folder and the a temporary change of the working directory might be needed.

Comment: This function is quite new to me.  When I run it in the R GUI with the following lines: `setwd('c:/users/mark w miller/simple R programs');
my.folder <- 'run_all_these';
sourceEntireFolder(my.folder);` I do not seem to obtain any output.  I feel silly asking, but what must I do to see the output?

Comment: If I change `echo=FALSE` to `echo=TRUE` and use the three lines of code in my previous comment then I see output in the default R GUI.

Comment: @MarkMiller, there is no reason to _expect_ output unless there is something in the files you are sourcing which would generate the output.  The `echo` flag simply shows you what's being executed at the moment.

Comment: But the example files are generating output.  They should print `c`.  Is there a way to show the result without using the `echo` command I mentioned above?

Comment: they're not printing `c`.  They are returning `c`.  It is different.  To print `c` use `print(c)`.   Also, don't use `c` as a variable name ;)

Comment: Okay.  So, how do I get your function to return `c`... ...without using the `echo` command?

Comment: Mark, the function above is simply a convenience wrapper around `source(.)`.  What does "return c" mean to you? What would you like to happen that you are not experiencing right now?

Comment: If I use the 3 lines of code in my 1st comment, then copy/paste your function into the default R GUI nothing is displayed.  I do not learn c = 30 from the 1st file or c = -10 from the 2nd file, etc.  I am not gaining information from using the function.  DWin's solution does tell me c = 30 the 1st time, -10 the 2nd, 200 the 3rd and 0.5 the 4th time.  Your function does tell me what I need to know if I change `echo` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`.  However, I got the impression from you that there is a better way to get that info.  If so, how?  I could just use DWin's answer.  Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: see my comment above about `print(c)`

Answer (score 4):

```
sapply( list.files(run_all_these, full.names=TRUE), source )
```

You would need to make sure that `run_all_these` was a valid Windows directory specification.

Comment: Good approach and just to run R-Files you could do 

`list.files('questionaries/', full.names=F, pattern='\\.[rR]$')`

Comment: You might also want to wrap/pipe that in `invisible()` to avoid unnecessary output.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have subfolders:

```
library(tidyverse)

list.files("name_folder", full.names = TRUE) %>% walk(source)
```