# How can I read multiple files in R

Tags: r, file, file-io

I have so many file(around 600) with these names:

```
x2008_1_3.txt
x2008_1_4.txt
x2008_1_5.txt
x2008_1_6.txt
x2008_1_7.txt
x2008_1_8.txt
.
.
.
.
x2009_1_3.txt
x2009_1_4.txt
x2009_1_5.txt
x2009_1_6.txt
x2009_1_7.txt
x2009_1_8.txt
.
.
.
.
```

I try so many ways to inter them as my infile all of them togather in R. But i still cannot have them all. i also want to make the output'names have the same name as input. any suggestion?

Comment: You are trying to read all these files into on dataset in R? If so, then I don't understand what you mean by output names having the same name as input. Can you explain some more?

Comment: yes i want to open them in R, plot them and then make the out put file that will have the same name as my input

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20083589/1492421

Answer (score 2):

You can set the files pattern to  `list.files` to get a list of the files:

```
list.files(path,pattern="^x[0-9]{4}_1_[0-9][.]txt",full.names = TRUE)
```

Set `recursive=TRUE` if your files in different directories.

Comment: how many pattern do i need? this is for all the month. so it will be 2008 12month 30 day for each month. i cannot understand your pattern

Comment: If you need to read in all files in a folder, then there is no need for pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the best at R but this may help it is a version of a script i use for something similar using CSV's

## Set dir, remember to use double \

```
directory = "Location of files you want imported" #IE c:\\Folder1\\Folder2
files = list.files(path=directory,pattern = "[.]txt") #Make a list of files, assuming you want all files in that folder

for(i in 1:length(files)) # loop though all files and use assign to create data frames or replace with a different function like read.csv or append ect..
{
  file = files[i]
  assign(file,read.table(paste(directory,file,sep = "\\"),sep="\t"))
}
```

I hope this helps a little!

Comment: i finnaly used this command: file<-(list.files(path,pattern='x200.*\\.txt', full.names=TRUE)