# Executing a script on a list of files in a directory in R

Tags: r, pdf, directory, text-mining, tm

I have a programme that enables me to convert pdf files into txt files using R. How do I apply this programme to a directory of pdf files that I want to convert to txt files?

This is the code I have so far that only works on a single url linked to a pdf document:

```
# download pdftotxt from 
# ftp://ftp.foolabs.com/pub/xpdf/xpdfbin-win-3.03.zip
# and extract to your program files folder

# here is a pdf for mining
url <- "http://www.noisyroom.net/blog/RomneySpeech072912.pdf"
dest <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
download.file(url, dest, mode = "wb")

# set path to pdftotxt.exe and convert pdf to text
exe <- "C:\\Program Files\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftotext.exe"
system(paste("\"", exe, "\" \"", dest, "\"", sep = ""), wait = F)

# get txt-file name and open it  
filetxt <- sub(".pdf", ".txt", dest)
shell.exec(filetxt); shell.exec(filetxt)    # strangely the first try always throws an error..


# do something with it, i.e. a simple word cloud 
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(Rstem)

txt <- readLines(filetxt) # don't mind warning..

txt <- tolower(txt)
txt <- removeWords(txt, c("\\f", stopwords()))

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
d <- data.frame(freq = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE))

# Stem words
d$stem <- wordStem(row.names(d), language = "english")

# and put words to column, otherwise they would be lost when aggregating
d$word <- row.names(d)

# remove web address (very long string):
d <- d[nchar(row.names(d)) < 20, ]

# aggregate freqeuncy by word stem and
# keep first words..
agg_freq <- aggregate(freq ~ stem, data = d, sum)
agg_word <- aggregate(word ~ stem, data = d, function(x) x[1])

d <- cbind(freq = agg_freq[, 2], agg_word)

# sort by frequency
d <- d[order(d$freq, decreasing = T), ]

# print wordcloud:
wordcloud(d$word, d$freq)

# remove files
file.remove(dir(tempdir(), full.name=T)) # remove files
```

Comment: lapply and list.files?

Comment: There are a couple of threads on this here on SO. This is pretty close of what you're after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083454/run-every-file-in-a-folder/20083517#20083517 You should turn your script into a function and pass that to `sapply`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for the tips! How do you apply this method onto a directory of files instead of a vector of URLs though?

Comment: Find files by `list.files` and pass the result (you may need to use `full.names` argument) to `sapply`. You need to modify the `crawlPDFs` function a bit - no need to download the file.

Answer (score 4):

If you have list (actually a vector) of urls to the files you're trying to process, you can just turn your procedure into a function and apply this procedure to every url. Try something along the lines of:

```
crawlPDFs <- function(x) {
  # x is a character string to the url on the web
  url <- x
  dest <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
  download.file(url, dest, mode = "wb")

  # set path to pdftotxt.exe and convert pdf to text
  exe <- "C:\\Program Files\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftotext.exe"
  system(paste("\"", exe, "\" \"", dest, "\"", sep = ""), wait = F)

  # get txt-file name and open it  
  filetxt <- sub(".pdf", ".txt", dest)
  shell.exec(filetxt); shell.exec(filetxt)    # strangely the first try always throws an error..


  # do something with it, i.e. a simple word cloud 
  library(tm)
  library(wordcloud)
  library(Rstem)

  txt <- readLines(filetxt) # don't mind warning..

  txt <- tolower(txt)
  txt <- removeWords(txt, c("\\f", stopwords()))

  corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
  corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
  tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
  m <- as.matrix(tdm)
  d <- data.frame(freq = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE))

  # Stem words
  d$stem <- wordStem(row.names(d), language = "english")

  # and put words to column, otherwise they would be lost when aggregating
  d$word <- row.names(d)

  # remove web address (very long string):
  d <- d[nchar(row.names(d)) < 20, ]

  # aggregate freqeuncy by word stem and
  # keep first words..
  agg_freq <- aggregate(freq ~ stem, data = d, sum)
  agg_word <- aggregate(word ~ stem, data = d, function(x) x[1])

  d <- cbind(freq = agg_freq[, 2], agg_word)

  # sort by frequency
  d <- d[order(d$freq, decreasing = T), ]

  # print wordcloud:
  wordcloud(d$word, d$freq)

  # remove files
  file.remove(dir(tempdir(), full.name=T)) # remove files
}

sapply(list.of.urls, FUN = crawlPDFs)
```

`list.of.urls` can be a character vector or a list where each list element is one character, a url to the pdf.